# Setting a date range on entry parameters

Tags: users, datetime

I'm working on a site that uses a date slider to select members of the site by birthdate. I want to show the users by gender and between two "ages". For example: Male, between 40 and 50 years old. The selection on gender works perfect, but I can't seem to get the lowest age set. 
This is does work; with only the lower date set.

```
{% set dateRange = '<= ' ~ lower_date %}

{% set queryParams = {
        geboortedatum : dateRange,
        order :'lastName'
    } 
%}
```

But once I set the upper age I've got an error.

```
{% set dateRange = '<= ' ~ lower_date ~ ' AND => ' ~ upper_date %}

{% set queryParams = {
        geboortedatum : dateRange,
        order :'lastName'
    } 
%}  

{% set leden = craft.users(queryParams) %}
{% set leden = craft.users(queryParams) %}
```

This gets this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object in /chroot/home/deacteur/deacteursgilde.be/craft/app/helpers/DbHelper.php on line 597
```

Can anyone help me out here? I'm totally lost... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I suspect it's going to come down to what the format of `lower_date` and `upper_date` are.  Can you update the question with those?

Comment: Also, isn't the operator wrong, shouldn't it be `>=`, not `=>`?

Comment: Our code now:
`{% set dateRange = '>= ' ~ upper_date ~ ' AND <= ' ~ lower_date %}
{% set queryParams = { search: { query: geslacht_param_string, attribute: 'geslacht' }, geboortedatum : dateRange, order :'lastName' } %}
{% set leden = craft.users(queryParams) %} 

{# a dump of the queryParams prints this: array(3) { ["search"]=> array(2) { ["query"]=> string(5) "vrouw" ["attribute"]=> string(8) "geslacht" } ["geboortedatum"]=> string(31) ">= 1946-06-13 AND <= 1965-06-13" ["order"]=> string(8) "lastName" } #} `


Without success, it won't pick the members between the range...